# reject accepts_nested_attributes_for multiple field blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails 4 app, I am using

```
 `accepts_nested_attributes_for :application, reject_if: proc { |attributes| attributes['uni_id'].blank? }`
```

But now I need to check it for multiple options. The pseudocode for what I want is something like this

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :application, reject_if: proc {
  (attributes['uni_id'].blank?  and attributes['duration'].blank?) OR (attributes['uni_id'].blank?  and attributes['semester'].blank?)

}
```

That is, reject if `(attributes['uni_id'].blank?  and attributes['duration'].blank?) OR (attributes['uni_id'].blank?  and attributes['semester'].blank?)`

Hope there might be some easy solution for this.

Comment: Did you try that logic?  Try replacing `and` with `&&` and `OR` with `||`.

Answer (score 2):

This is working for me

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :application, reject_if: proc { |attributes| 
  (attributes['uni_id'].blank?  && attributes['duration'].blank?) || (attributes['uni_id'].blank?  && attributes['semester'].blank?)

}
```